# Aria Labelling and Alt Attribute

Tags: html, accessibility

Getting quite confused when deciding which attributes should go where on the below code:

```
<div class="image-container">
   <img src="images/Local/col-3/03 Rooftops.jpg" />
       <div class="image-overlay">
          <div class="image-title">Rooftops</div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Assistance placing the Alt attribute, the aria-label and if 'role' is required on the image-container would be great.

Thanks

Comment: There is no `alt` tag. `alt` is a *universal attribute*.

Comment: Note: HTML does not use and does not need or require a closing slash on `<img>` and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob It does allow for it though, so nothing wrong with the HTML shown.

Comment: @connexo And why would you do that when it does nothing, means nothing and has no effect?

Comment: @Rob That discussion would be getting us nowhere, which is why this will be my last comment on the topic. There are reasons the spec explicitly allows it, it's valid, that's all I need to know.

Comment: @connexo The reason it's allowed is to not break code for all those who, in the past, thought we were all heading to XHTML on the web. That is the only reason it's allowed but it is not specified or required in any HTML spec and never has been. So, again, why would you do that with new HTML code? It's pointless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230978/discussion-between-connexo-and-rob).

Comment: Updated the title. Alt *attribute*. Question still stands if you have any response. Thanks

Comment: *which tags should go where*, *Assistance placing the Alt tag* still talking about *tags* when you actually mean *attributes*.

Comment: Aside from that, using semantical HTML would help your code alot with regard to accessibility. Why is your whole construct not a `<figure>` element?

Comment: Does the question make more sense for you now? Thanks

Comment: Figure, okay. I will check that out. Thanks. Assuming I change the div to a figure, any input on the question?

Comment: What reason do you have for not applying the alt attribute to the `<img>` tag?

Comment: Unsure if the alt attribute would move to the div image-container if that was to need the role='img' attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic principle of ARIA, the standard behind `role` attributes is to avoid them, if you can use semantic HTML elements: [The first rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#firstrule)

So to your end, there is the `<figure>` element, which allows grouping media with a `<figcaption>`. It seems this would be appropriate for your use case.

Most critical for accessibility is to provide an alternative text in the alt attribute, which describes the image, if it's informational. For example "Rooftops with people socialising" or the like.

If your caption for sighted users is explanatory enough to non-sighted ones, you might leave alt empty, but its presence is mandatory: `alt=""`.

```
<figure class="image-container">
   <img src="images/Local/col-3/03 Rooftops.jpg" alt="Rooftops with people socialising" />
   <figcaption class="image-overlay">
      <div class="image-title">Rooftops</div>
   </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Now this was the theory based on the standards. For the quirky reality though, with different browsers and screen readers supporting different parts, you might need a mixture to support certain versions. See [Scott O'Hara's article from 2019 on figure support in different browsers/screenreaders](https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2019/01/21/how-do-you-figure.html).

If, for some reason, you cannot use semantically correct HTML, there is the `figure` role, and by means of `aria-labelledby` you can establish an association between the figure and it's caption: [ARIA:figure role and example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Figure_Role)

Comment: Hi Andy, this is really useful. My example forms 1 of roughly 24 images that make up an image gallery. I guess your answer still stands - use the figure element for each image-container div.

Comment: Yes, you would also mark up a gallery like that. I added a link to a good article about support of figure.